# Is it possible to call controller if ng-if condition is true?

Tags: angularjs

I have two controllers on same page. What I am trying to achieve is if specific value is 1 call controller 1 and if 0 then controller 2. But the problem is that I am getting value inside controllers which is not accessible outside the controller, so how can I achieve this?

Comment: You can make use of resolve while routing to that page in order to choose between your controllers... How you getting that Specific value? through the service call?

Comment: Yes. im calling two different service calls..

Comment: then i guess you can call those service while routing to that page in the resolve method, based on the value you get from the http response , you can assign controller to that template

Answer (score 0):

This case calls for a service, which can be shared between controllers.

All you have to do is inject the service into both controllers and update the variable in the service.

```
angular.module('app').service('myService', function() {
  var self = this;
  self.isActive;

  self.setActive = function(val) {
     self.isActive = val;
  };

  self.getActive = function() {
    return self.isActive;
})
. controller('first', function(myService) {
  var isActive = myService.getActive();
})
. controller('second', function(myService) {
  var isActive = myService.getActive();
})
```

Both controllers would have the same value, you would just have to handle managing them during the life cycle of your app via the controllers.

Note that you can do anything you want in a service in terms of logic, you just have to share the service with the required controllers. It would be more likely that a function would handle the logic which you are splitting into different controllers.

```
// Inside the service
self.handleActive = function(isActive) {
  if (isActive) {
    // Do something
  } else {
    // Do other
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use directive for this purpose

```
global.directive('dynamicCtrl', ['$compile', '$parse',function($compile, 
 $parse) {
 return {
restrict: 'A',
terminal: true,
priority: 100000,
link: function(scope, elem) {
  var name = $parse(elem.attr('dynamic-ctrl'))(scope);
  elem.removeAttr('dynamic-ctrl');
    // add your condition here
     if(condition == true){
     elem.attr('ng-controller',"first");
       }
     else{
      elem.attr('ng-controller',"second");
     }
  $compile(elem)(scope);
}
};
}]);
```

use in html as

Comment: How will i use this directive on my page? And also the value which im gonna use in your if condition is coming from the service which is defined inside controller.

Comment: How can you define a service inside a controller ? if it is a function write it in a angular service and call it inside directive

Comment: Sorry i defined in factory and calling from there. Two services with different values like one is 'dealer' and second is 'buyer'. so in my page when buyer service is called i want to call buyer controller and if dealer then dealer controller on same page.

Comment: call these services in the config part of the app and assign it to the global variable before any controller loads. var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.run(function(){
  // service call
} and check that global variable in diretive